Why is the First Law of Thermodynamic related to Fluid Equation?
In Cosmology, there is a equation called Fluid Equation:
$$\dot{{\varepsilon}}+3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}(\varepsilon+P)=0.$$
It is derived by taking time derivative of the First Law of Thermodynamic:
$\dot{E}+P\dot{V}=dQ$, where $dQ=0$ because the expansion of the universe is a adiabatic process.
My question is why can the First Law of Thermodynamic be used in the expansion of the universe when it is meant for thermodynamic not cosmology, why is the expansion of universe related to the pressure exerted by matter or radiation, also how would matter/radiation exert pressure to the universe itself?

The laws of thermodynamics are universal. If the number of particles in the system is huge (such as our universe) then it obeys the laws of thermodynamics regardless of its contituents.

That explains it, thank you!
